# Tokio spawn, move reference to self

Tags: rust, rust-tokio

I have a struct with a database client:

```rust
pub struct Crawler {
    database_client: mongodb::Client,
}
```

There is a method:

```rust
pub async fn start(&self) {
    while let Some(value) = stream.next().await {
        tokio::spawn(async move { self.save_to_db(value) }).await;
    }
}
```

The compiler says:

```
 tokio::spawn(async move { self.save_to_db(value) }).await;
    |             ^^^^^^^^^^^^ future returned by `save_to_db` is not `Send`
```

As far as I understand, this is because the spawn'ed task could run on another thread which could outlives the original one. I'm pretty sure this won't happen, so how can I solve this? I tried a lot of approaches including `Arc` / `Rc` / and channels, but I can't make it work.

Comment: It's hard to answer your question because it doesn't include a [MRE]. We can't tell what crates (and their versions), types, traits, fields, etc. are present in the code. It would make it easier for us to help you if you try to reproduce your error on the [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org) if possible, otherwise in a brand new Cargo project, then [edit] your question to include the additional info. There are [Rust-specific MRE tips](//stackoverflow.com/tags/rust/info) you can use to reduce your original code for posting here. Thanks!

Comment: The error is because the future includes a type which isn't `Send`, and so can't be passed to another thread safely. There's nothing more we can guess without a minimal reproducible example though.